# Web app using Azure active directory for Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am using the below sample code to create a simple web app (I have not incorporated web API yet)
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

I was able to debug the application without any errors. But when I deployed the app to Azure, I followed the steps to change the 
1) Sign-On URL
2) Reply URL
to the web site address.
Now when I try to access my website it tries to authenticate me and then it just gives me back status code 500.
Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sample should not require ANY DB. The cache used there is the `NaiveTokenCache` (see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/tree/master/TodoListWebApp/Utils), which uses the Http session.
Either you modified the sample to switch the cache, or you are talking about something else (in which case, I recommend specifying the exact bits you are dealing with).

Comment: Yes I had used the cache that was part of the default ASP.NET project template that get's created when using Org Auth. Thank you vibronet, after switching to the session cache that is part of the sample, it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Would you mind marking this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable SSL on your website and the return url is the https url. When you change the https url, shut down the webserver and re-run.

Comment: Thank you Mostafa, I did add the SSL certificate, but now I am getting an error where it tries to find compact SQL Server (the one used by ADALTokenCache.cs) using EntityFramework.
I have uploaded the .mdf/.ldf files to App_Data directory.
Any idea what can I do that to fix this issue.

Comment: Here is the exception I get:
SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]